# Long ajax respond time?

Tags: php, ajax, tcp

Based on my understanding ajax respond(return) can not be more than a couple of seconds. So is there any way you can ajax every couple minute or second and check if result is ready(php finished).

The reason I am asking is because my php code is sending data over tcp which it take around 20 min, and I want check the result and show it on the browser.

Right now I am writing the result on file, and then every minute I ajax to another php file which read that file to check it.

Comment: How much data are you trying to send? Is the PHP operation taking 20 minutes or does the actual transfer of data over TCP take 20 minutes?

Comment: We are send 3000+ item file to 5-15 scales, and speed its all depend how fast scale can process it. (scales are slow so we have to wait for scale). Time is vary between 5-20min